# Выровнять текст в центре контейнера

Tags: html, css

Как выровнять текст по центру (по вертикали и по горизонтали) внутри контейнера без изменения шрифта?

```css
.box{ 
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #f3a500;
  text-align: center;
  font: caption; 
  font-size: 28px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">+</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.box{ 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #f3a500;
  text-align: center;
  font: caption; 
  font-size: 28px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">+</div>
```